# Zend Framework - Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception'

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

can someone help?
I have issue with sending mail from website (eshop) after order confirmation.
Zend fremework is used to 2 identically eshop. Both use the same classes, same settings, on one it works fine and on the other one crashes with this error:

**Settings:**

Zend framework, Eshop, PHP version 5.3

**MAIL**

- mail.encoding      = UTF-8
- mail.useSmtp       = true
- mail.smtp.server   = mail.*******.**
- mail.smtp.port   = 465
- mail.smtp.ssl   = ssl
- mail.smtp.auth     = login
- mail.smtp.username = ******@******.**
- mail.smtp.password = **********

**ISSUE**

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message 'No connection has been                        established to mail8.hostmaster.sk' in              /home/hn003000/www_root/ShibumiFramework/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php:312 Stack trace:
**#0** /home/hn003000/www_root/ShibumiFramework/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php(370):     Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_receive(300)
**#1** /home/hn003000/www_root/ShibumiFramework/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(199): Z Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_expect(220, 300)
**#2**/home/hn003000/www_root/ShibumiFramework/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(198): Z Ze Znd_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->helo('localhost')
**#3** /home/hn003000/www_root/ShibumiFramework/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(349): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()
**#4**/home/hn003000/www_root/ShibumiFramework/Zend/Mail.php(960): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Shibumi_Mail))
**#5**/home/hn003000/www_root/ShibumiFramework/Shibumi/Mail.php(27): Zend_Mail->send(Object(Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp))
**#6** /home/hn003000/www_root/www_akva24/application/modules/catalog/controllers/ in /home/hn003000/www_root/ShibumiFramework/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php on line 312

**Thanks for answers**

I tried change to TLS

I tried another mail server

Requests did not arrive on the mail server

Comment: What is the minimum TLS version that your mail server will accept? Is that version available in phpinfo()? Is this Zend Framework 1?

Answer (score 0):

My hosting privider blocked php mail function on my site!
After they fixed it (a week of convincing that the fault is with them) it works.
Thanks, solved